# Spring Batch Multi Line Header and Footer

Tags: spring-batch

I need to write a job where I need to write two lines(only) of header and two lines(only) of footer. 
My header would be as below

```
recordType FileName --Header Ln 1
JobName Date --Header Ln 2
```

My footer would be as below

```
JobRowCount JobTotalAmount --Footer Ln 1
recordType FileName Date --Footer Ln 2
```

We need one header/footer at File level and another header/footer at Job level. We are planning to have one file(aggregated file) for multiple jobs and each job would have its own header footer and the whole file would have header and footer.

My data rows are simple one line and I achieved with FlatFileItemWriter and DelimitedLineAggregator

How can we achieve this? I tried writer.writeHeader twice but its printing in same line.

Is there any option?

For now I have a dirty fix for this issue as below but would appreciate a better approach

```
public void writeFooter(final Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("Footer Ln 1");
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write("Footer Ln 2");
    }
```

Comment: Why is using a newline character considered a "dirty fix"?

Comment: As my file is an aggregated file for few of my jobs, so lets say if I have 2 jobs my file would be as below
HeaderAgregated
HeaderJob1
dataline1
dataline2
FooterJob1
HeaderJob2
dataline1
dataline2
FooterJob2
FooterAgregated
and using newline doesnt work for multiple jobs

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use headecallback and footercallback inertface in itemwrite as following -

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.spr...FlatFileItemWriter"> <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" /> <property name="lineAggregator" ref="lineAggregator"/> <property name="headerCallback" ref="headerCallback" /> <property name="footerCallback" ref="footerCallback" /> </bean>
```

Comment: I do have my itemWriter as you specified and I am able to see header and footer. My issue is I need two header lines and 2 footer lines. One Header/Footer is at File Level and One Header/Footer is at Job Level. We are planning to use same file for multiple Jobs.